# Compare two dataframes, show differences and missing values as Excel export

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to compare two data sources and present the differences in an Excel overview in an understandable way. Differences in price and quantity should be visible (marked in red), but also missing values.

With my previous attempt to solve it with pandas, I do not come to my desired result and hope that someone on this platform can help me (at this point already many thanks).

My attempt:

```
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter

data1 = [('CUS001', 'Apple', '778899', '01.09.2021 - 01.10.2021', 15.50, 9), ('CUS001', 'Banana', '554466', '01.09.2021 - 14.09.2021', 12.99, 12), ('CUS001', 'Banana', '554466', '15.09.2021 - 01.10.2021', 15.50, 9), ('CUS001', 'Orange', '112233', '01.09.2021 - 01.10.2021', 20.00, 10), ('CUS002', 'Apple', '778899', '01.09.2021 - 01.10.2021', 15.50, 20), ('CUS002', 'Banana', '554466', '01.09.2021 - 01.10.2021', 12.99, 19)]
data2 = [('CUS001', 'CC-778899', 'Apple', 15.50, 10), ('CUS001', 'CC-554466', 'Banana', 12.99, 12), ('CUS002', 'CC-778899', 'Apple', 15.50, 10), ('CUS002', 'CC-554466', 'Banana', 10.50, 9)]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data1, columns = ['Customer', 'Product', 'ArtNr', 'Charge Interval', 'Price', 'Qty'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=data2, columns = ['Customer', 'ArtNr', 'Product', 'Price', 'Qty'])

df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis='columns')


writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pd_try.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

The result so far:

[image]

The result I want to achieve:

[image]

Can this be solved with pandas at all?

// EDIT

Group by customer and add key. Is this possible?

[image]

Comment: Your second DataFrame will need a `Charge Interval` column too. Or better yet, let both `df1` and `df2` have an `order_id` column. Otherwise there is no way to automate the join you want to achieve, because `Price` and `Qty` are not unique, so they cannot be used as keys.

Comment: I read something that you can only do a compare if both dataframes have the same number of rows. If this is true, my plan can't work like this, or is there any way to make it work?

Comment: It's not true that both DataFrames have to be the same length. Of course you can only compare those rows that appear in both. For that to work, you need a common key to identify which rows belong to each other, as stated above.

Comment: Alright, but how can I extend the shorter dataframe by the number of keys so I can do my matching?

I tried with an insert

`df1.insert(0, 'key', df1.index +1)`
`df2.insert(0, 'key', df1.index +1)`

but get the error

`ValueError: Length of values (6) does not match length of index (4)`

Comment: If you can't extract the keys from the data source, you'll have to set one of the key columns manually, based on your knowledge of which rows belong to each other, e,g.: `df2.insert(0, 'key', [1, 2, 5, 6])`

Comment: The problem is that each dataframe can be smaller or larger than the other. Both dataframes already come sorted by customer number and quantity, which should theoretically make matching easier. Next I would have to group both dataframes by customer number and leave the differences empty and just give a key. If it looks like this in the end, a comparison should be possible.